# How to start validation only after the user's INPUT in PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, email, bootstrap-4

I need to create a "Contact Us" page using PHP and I must validate the data before sending.

Below is the code I tried.

```php
<?php
$error_messages = [];
if (!filter_var($_POST[email_user], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
array_push($error_messages, 'O E-mail informado não é válido!');
} if(!empty($_POST[subject_user])) {
array_push($error_messages, 'O campo assunto não pode está vazio!');
} if(!empty($_POST[message_user])) {
array_push($error_messages, 'Você precisa escrever uma mensagem para que possamos ajudar você!');
}
if(empty($error_messages)) {
$headers = "FROM: contact@example.com";
mail("personal-email@example.com", $subject_user, $message_user, $headers );
} else {
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>";
echo "Você precisa corrigir isso antes de fazer o envio deste formulário:<br>";
foreach ($error_messages as $item) {
echo "- ".$item."<br>";
}
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

You can see the complete code here:
https://pastebin.com/5PKYqgn4

Você precisa corrigir isso antes de fazer o envio deste formulário:

- O E-mail informado não é válido!

Comment: What kind of validation do you want?

Comment: There are three. 1) If the email is valid. 2) If the "Subject" field is not empty. 3) If the "Message" field is not empty. I've done this in PHP code as you can see above, but when the page is executed this validation is done. I would like the data to be validated only after the user's INPUT.

Comment: Please give few more attempts before posting the question to Stackoverflow. There should be hundreds of thoursdands of code over internet showcasing form validations in Php. If you can't use them, please let us know what is the unique part you would like to do.

Comment: Im beginner in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all your validation rules inside:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
//here goes your validations
}
```

Comment: Hello,

Javascript should never be used to resolve this problem. This is because it is a client-side technology, which means that it can easily circumvent and send invalid data to my form. I will do the Javascript equivalent at a later time so as to guide the user during typing, but at the moment it is necessary to do the validation via PHP.

Comment: You should change the title of your question, to make it clearer that you want your code to be executed only after form's submission. I edited the answer to fit your response to catcon's comment.

Comment: The title is correct. See the final "in php". Thanks for your comments, I'll test and I'll return.

Comment: I think you should use client side validation using java script as well as server side validation using php.

Comment: Exactly, ideally both validations should be used, but the server side is mandatory while the client side is optional. I am finalizing the project and I chose not to use any Javascript, this is because if you put "input type email" in HTML the browser itself will make the necessary validations and inform the user when typing.